# How can I add strikethrough property by clicking the button next to the element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, for-loop, addeventlistener

I am new to coding, and I am trying to make a shopping list app although I ran into some problem.
I am trying to select the elements of a table, it has two columns one for the shopping item and one for buttons next to each item. I want to click the button next to the item and with that add a css style of strikethrough but only for that respective item. But now i can click any "Mark as buyed button" and will apply the styles for all the items, and after that sort the items in ascending or descending order with two other buttons. A little help/hint would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance, if my post is not that clear please do tell

Here is my code:
[My code](https://codepen.io/szabidev/pen/wvdbXoa)

```js
let addItem = document.querySelector('.add-item');
let input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
let table = document.querySelector('.list');
let tbody = document.querySelector('.tbody');

let ascBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-asc');
let descBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-desc');

// let itemsToSort = document.querySelector('.shopping-list-item');
// let shoppingItems = [];

addItem.addEventListener('click', addItemToList);
// ascBtn.addEventListener('click', ascend);
// descBtn.addEventListener('click', descend);

function addItemToList() {
    if (input.value !== '') {

        let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
        let firstTableData = document.createElement('td');
        let secondTableData = document.createElement('td');
        let actionBtn = document.createElement('button');
        actionBtn.className = 'action-btn btn';
        actionBtn.innerText = 'Mark as buyed';
        firstTableData.className = 'shopping-list-item';
        tbody.appendChild(tableRow);
        firstTableData.innerHTML = input.value;
        tableRow.appendChild(firstTableData);
        secondTableData.appendChild(actionBtn)
        tableRow.appendChild(secondTableData);
        input.value = '';
        // console.log(firstTableData, secondTableData)
        // shoppingItems.push(input.value);

    }
}

input.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);

function keyPress(e) {
    if (input.value !== '' && e.keyCode == 13) {

        let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
        let firstTableData = document.createElement('td');
        let secondTableData = document.createElement('td');
        let actionBtn = document.createElement('button');
        actionBtn.className = 'action-btn btn';
        actionBtn.innerText = 'Mark as buyed';
        firstTableData.className = 'shopping-list-item';
        tbody.appendChild(tableRow);
        firstTableData.innerHTML = input.value;
        tableRow.appendChild(firstTableData);
        secondTableData.appendChild(actionBtn)
        tableRow.appendChild(secondTableData);
        input.value = '';

    }
}

table.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // console.log(e.target)
    // console.log('this works')
    let dynamicTd = document.querySelectorAll('.shopping-list-item');
    if (e.target && e.target.className == 'action-btn btn') {
        // console.log('this works too');
        for (let i = 0; i < dynamicTd.length; i++) {
            console.log(dynamicTd[i]);
            dynamicTd[i].className = 'checked';
        }

    }
})

// function ascend(a, b) {
//     let item = shoppingItems.value;
//     console.log(item);
// }

// function descend() {

// }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #6c757d;
}

.shopping-list {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2a9d8f;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 200;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.form {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.form input {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.form button {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.btn-container {
  width: 50%;
}

.btn-container .btn {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.list {
  background-color: #a8dadc;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.list th {
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.list td {
  width: 60%;
}

.action-btn {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Shopping List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="shopping-list">
        <h2 class="header">Shopping List</h2>
        <!-- prevent from submitting and disappearing of items add onsubmit -->
        <form class="form" onsubmit="return false">
            <input type="text">
                    <!-- prevent from submitting and disappearing of items add type='button' -->
            <button type="button" class="add-item btn">Add Item</button>
        </form>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <button class="btn-asc btn">Sort asc</button>
            <button class="btn-desc btn">Sort desc</button>
        </div>
        <table class="list">
            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tbody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Here is my code` - no, put it in the question - not all of it, a minimal complete and verifiable example that demonstrates your problem

Comment: Store a count of items and add the count each item and button as they're added to the basket thing, kind of like an ID that increments. So the first row would look like `<p data-item-id="1">test</p><button data-item-id="1">Mark as bought</button>` in the inspector.

You can then use that to do `document.querySelector(\`p[data-item-id="${item_id}"]\`)` and add your strikethrough.

Comment: Hi, you can also use [SO code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355) to reproduce your codes. I help you to add it this time.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, it was my first maybe second post. I'll be more carefull to not flood the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse up the DOM using [Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) before selecting the `td` using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to apply the `checked` class.

```
table.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.className == "action-btn btn") {
    const td = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("td")
    if (td) {
      td.className = "checked";
    }
  }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/RwVmBPr)

[image]

Comment: Yup, thank you very much, I tought it should be easier than what I wrote. Thank you for the fix!!!

Comment: @SzabiVojtek, please accept the answer if you find it useful to your question and people may find it helpful in the future as well.

Comment: How can I accept it? I voted for it, but it says I dont have enough rep. to vote, but mu feedback was recorded. Im pretty new here

Comment: @SzabiVojtek you should be able to click on the tick ✔ to accept. According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges you can upvote with 15 rep, which you now appear to have

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `for` loop within method added to table as click listener to: `e.target.parentElement.previousSibling.className = 'checked'`.

But it is not the best solution. A better way to do this would be to store list items as objects in an array and add the dataset to the delete button. Then you can simply remove that array element based on dataset attribute.